# Visual Studio 2017で波括弧( { )を入力して改行したときに自動でインデントされない

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017で括弧が補完された後で改行してもインデントが挿入されません。
どうすればよいのでしょうか?

私の環境では、波括弧を入力すると自動的に補完され、下のようなカーソル位置になります。 
(`|`がカーソルを表しています)

```
if (a == "a") {|}
```

この状態でEnterを押すと

```
if (a == "a") {
|}
```

というようになってしまいます。

これを

```
if (a == "a") {
    |
}
```

というように改行したときに自動的にインデントが入るようにしたいのですがどうすればよいのでしょうか?

ちなみにインデント幅は4スペースです。
言語はC/C++を想定しています

Comment: ファイルの拡張子ごとにルールが異なると思うのですが、ファイル拡張子は何ですか？また、整形して欲しい言語はどの言語なのでしょうか？

Comment: 使っている言語はC/C++です

Answer (score 1):

当方環境では、オプション画面で
テキストエディター>C#>タブ を選択し、
・インデント：スマート
に設定すれば期待の動作となりました。

ただし、括弧の自動補完直後に改行を入れないと、

```
if (a == "a") {
|}
```

このようになるようです。